My uploaded images are rotated with laravel / intervention
I am using intervention to manipulate some images with Laravel 11.
My code works fine in local environment.
When I deploy the application in production (heroku), the same code produces a surprising phenomenon: the image undergoes a rotation, sometimes by 90°, sometimes by 180°.
And the same image is not rotared locally, but is in production !
I tried to play with the "autoOrientation" parameter, without success. The image is still rotated.
My code is very simple :
$manager = new ImageManager(new Driver);
$image = $manager->read($media);
$image->save('transformed_image');

I read here and there that there is a story about "exif" data. Is this an indication ?
What could be my mistake ?

Yes, the idea about EXIF is very logical. You can try to forcefully use EXIF data via:
$image->orientate();

But check that the required php extension is installed
php -m | grep exif

if not, than
sudo apt-get install php-exif

Update:
It seems that for Heroku for php7.4 or later the extension exif should be enabled through the composer:
{
    "require": {
        "ext-exif": "*"
    }
}


I already tried the orient() method. Without success. What I do not understand is why it works fine locally and not in production (heroku)

It may depend on the extensions installed on Heroku. Have you tried running the php -m command locally and on Heroku and comparing the list?

I'm also update my answer with note for install exif extension for Heroku

You were right ! exif extension is installed on my computer. And it is not installed on heroku. See here. I just add a require in my composer.json and now it works like a charm !
